# Change installation path of Minecraft Launcher? (Not the game)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

When downloading and installing the minecraft launcher from the offical website, there is no step for me to choose the install path and its always in `C:\XboxGames`. Anyway for me to change the path into `C:\GameLaunchers`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! When I downloaded and ran the legacy `.msi` launcher install from [Mojang](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download), it asked where I wanted to install the launcher. Set that to your target directory and you are good to go! You might experience issues because Windows is *very* picky about where you store your files. `C:/` is your root directory, and Windows likes you to store and install your stuff in your user directory.

If this still causes problems and simply doesn't work or you want an easier-to-use experience, you might consider using a different launcher like [MultiMC](https://multimc.org/), [CurseForge](https://www.curseforge.com/download/app), or [ATLauncher](https://atlauncher.com/downloads). They make it significantly easier to add mods and manage the location of your installations. I assume you're using Windows, so all these launchers are available for you to use. I have used all these launchers and I personally recommend CurseForge. It is very user-friendly and has access to arguably the largest modpack database in the Minecraft community.

If you use Linux, or if anyone comes across this post with a similar issue, you can go to the same link but install the `Other Distributions` tarball and run `tar -xzf minecraft.tar.gz`. This will create a `/minecraft` directory you can move where you like. All the launchers I mentioned work for Linux *except* CurseForge. They still haven't added Minecraft support for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So basically I'll assume its not able to do it with the latest launcher — just Microsoft doing Microsoft things.